# GET запрос в HTTP?

Tags: http, get, rest

Почему нельзя отправлять файлы через GET запрос в HTTP? И что произойдет, если отправить файл через GET запрос?

Comment: Как это нельзя? GET site.com/upload.php?fileName=foo?content=00010203...

Comment: Можно, но не нужно

Comment: Маленькие файлы так отправить можно, но это некошерно.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka мне - вполне кошерно. И еще DWORD или два для аттрибутов файла - вообще супер будет!

Comment: Но содержимое файла будет видно в командной строке.

Answer (score 1):

Существует ограничение на длину GET-запроса - 2048. Поэтому вы можете передавать только файлы длиной меньше 2 кб и только текстовые файлы. Содержимое файла будет передаваться через URL, поэтому его нельзя сохранить в тайне.

Comment: Последнее предложение непонятно, почему URL нельзя сохранить в тайне?

Comment: Любой может открыть ваш браузер и, начиная вводить адрес сайта, он из истории может увидеть, что вы передавали. Это может увидеть сисадмин или провайдер.

Comment: Во-первых, мой браузер защищён паролями и шифрованием жёсткого диска (и я просто никого физически не подпускаю к своим устройствам), во-вторых, сисадмин или провайдер точно так же смогут увидеть целиком и содержимое POST-запроса тоже :)

Comment: У вас - да. Не у всех.

Comment: @andreymal, тело POST-запроса нигде не сохраняется. В случае же GET адрес страницы, в котором и передаются параметры (вида `page.php?param1=value1&param2=value2`), сохраняется в истории браузера и на кэширующих прокси-серверах. В придачу, Google Chrome [любит (предположительно) сливать все посещённые им непубличные страницы в поисковый индекс](https://roem.ru/28-07-2011/120474/google-chrome-otpravlyaet-kontent-stranic-v-indeks/). Плюс GET по стандарту нельзя использовать для изменения чего-то, только для чтения.

Comment: `длиной меньше 2 кб и только текстовые файлы` — нет, не только текстовые (если трактовать двоичный поток как текст в кодировке UTF-8), но тогда urlencoding (`%AB`) потребует по три символа на двоичный байт. Получится 682 байта без учёта длины имени сайта и пути до страницы-приёмника.